# How can open two links in one click?

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, blogger

I have a Blogger website. I want when users click any links to open any page or post it should open abother link in a new window and at the same time it also should open the main link of that particular post or page. This should auto update to every links on the blogger website. Is there is any way. The link it should redirect is a ads link. That's why I need it. This problem is hard to describe.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an actual answer,

Opening multiple links at the same time will destroy all of the user experience and your website's reputation as well. And if you are redirecting for some ads website then it will be of no use since now a days AdBlocker is installed by majority of users.

You can serve non-intrusive ads and maintain over user experience as well. like facebook and google does.